# How to use X11 forwarding with PuTTY

Tags: windows-7, linux, ssh, x11-forwarding

I have a VM with RHEL 5 without an X server. My host has Windows 7.

I need to connect to the VM and redirect the X11 output of the commands to my host.

I know that if my host were a GNU/Linux machine it would be as easy as ssh -X .

I'm using PuTTy to connect by SSH to the VM, I tried enabling X11 forward option in PuTTY config, but nothing happened.

Have you ever done this? I'm quite advanced with GNU/Linux, but a newbie with this toy of Winbug$ 7.

Comment: if you've enabled putty's X11-forwarding option, you're halfway there.  that's all you need on the PuTTY side; RHEL is good to go; now you need an X server to display to.  (Windows is not an X-server.)  Cygwin and Xming both provide free x-servers for Windows, but i don't know how well they work on Win-7.  there are commercial options as well.

Comment: "I have a VM with RHEL 5 without an X server." you need an xserver of some sort to forward x.

Comment: Here is a decent guide in case the accepted answer isnt clear as to what you need to do with Xming/Xlaunch: http://www.seas.upenn.edu/cets/answers/x11-forwarding.html

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You need a X server on your windows workstation.
A couple popular options include:

- [vcxsrv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/)
- [Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/) (non-free)
- [X410](https://x410.dev/) (non-free)

You need your SSH server to have the `X11Forwarding yes` set in the `sshd_config`.  It also needs at least the [xauth](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/xauth) binary/package, but you may want to install your distrobutions version of [X11 base clients](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/xbase-clients).

In putty all you should have to do check the **Enable X11 forewarding** box under Connections\SSH\X11 in your putty connection.

[image: putty x11 settings]

Putty documentation for X11 forwarding

- http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.63/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-x-forwarding
- http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.63/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-ssh-x11

Man pages for sshd/sshd_config

- https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sshd(8)
- https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sshd_config(5)

Comment: Even though XMing shows me that it's display 0:0 on my system, when I filled in `localhost:0:0` to the "X display location" field, the forwarding did not work. Just leaving this field empty is the best thing you can do ;)

Comment: Note that Xming *does* work with Windows 10, although it's not specified on their webpage.

Comment: @Joce.. Agree.. `Xming` is amazing.. even though its a bit old..

Comment: You may need edit as admin: C:\Program Files\Xming\X0.hosts and add your VM IP address and restart xming.

Comment: My 2 cents: I tried the above methods.  With Xming/putty I needed to put the localhost:0.0 in my config.  This document worked for my setup[https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/how-to-enable-x11-forwarding-from-red-hat-enterprise-linux-rhel-amazon-linux-suse-linux-ubuntu-server-to-support-gui-based-installations-from-amazon-ec2/]

Answer (score 1):

you could use MobaXterm against the putty.
https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/download.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Agree - MobaXterm was a quick solution, since Xming seems quite old and is not free to use (if one does not use it on a regular basis). Download, install, start SSH connection, then call the application. Note: there was a font-related error, so on the Host, set: `export LC_ALL=C`. Should do the job. Also, make sure that in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, `X11Forwarding yes` is set.