# Access Remote Enterprise Server RHEL desktop environment from Windows

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-desktop, kde

We have a remote RHEL virtual machine in a server without any desktop environment like GNOMe or KDE.

The only way I can connect to this system (ssh) is using MobaXterm/Putty. I have installed KDE using Yum. Now, how can I connect from my windows system to the remote system's Desktop environment.

I am aware of X11, to run certains apps with GUI, but that will not serve the purpose. We want to access the full desktop of the remote machine.

Thanks,
Rohit

Comment: Maybe use something like VNC?

Comment: If the remote system has no desktop environment, your question is not clear, because you then state you wanted to connect to the remote system's Desktop environment (which of course does not exist).  Anyways, Teamviewer can run on RHEL have you tried that?

Comment: If the installation now has a desktop environment, why even mention the fact, it didn't have one?  I am honestly confused by your question.

Comment: Initially it did not have any desktop environment. But then I installed KDE, but I cannot start it from my remote system.

Comment: You should be able to start the KDE from SSH, you might not be able to interact with the desktop environment over SSH, but you should be able to start andor kill it.  Are you sure you configured KDE properly?

Comment: Your question uses the word “remote” four times.   What, *exactly,* do you mean by “remote”, and why do you believe that it is so important to the question?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to

- install a XWindows server on your Windows PC ([yes, "server"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System#Software_architecture)),
- connect to you Unix system via SSH, enabling XWindows forwarding (if using the SSH command this is `ssh -X ...`, and PuTTY also has such an option)
- No need to start a X server on the remote host (the X server is your local PC...)
- Start the GUI apps on the remote, and they will create Windows on you PC.

See [How to use X11 forwarding with PuTTY](https://superuser.com/questions/119792/how-to-use-x11-forwarding-with-putty#119908) for details.

Comment: We want a full desktop environment, Is that possible?

Comment: How "full" is "full"? Desktop with taskbar? The anwer is also yes (these are just windows...) but do you really need this? For the record I work with a lot of different Linux servers and I don't run any desktop apps on them, but the GUI apps on my Linux PC let me access the files on the servers transparently almost as if they were local.