# Setting up X11 forwarding over SSH on Windows 10 Subsystem for Linux?

Tags: windows-10, xorg, windows-subsystem-for-linux, x11-forwarding

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ connected to my local network and I can SSH into it with no problems. This does cause some problems though as everything is done on the command line.

What I would really like to do is use X11 forwarding by using the SSH client that comes with Windows Subsystem for Linux. I am running Windows 10 Pro with the 1803 update installed.

I'm just curious about how I might go about using this feature? If it won't work in Windows 10 natively then I can always run a Linux virtual machine to connect to the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: See also [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1457/x11-forwarding-with-xming-over-ssh/101924#101924) for a solution using Cygwin.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is definitely possible given your current setup. Note that you also have the option of [using Putty](https://superuser.com/questions/119792/how-to-use-x11-forwarding-with-putty) but either way, you'll need to have an X server running on the client machine, your Windows Subsystem for Linux — [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux). The [client-server model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System#Software_architecture) of the X window system is partially what makes X forwarding so easy to pull off. All you need is an X server running on host and client.

### Raspberry Pi (Host) Configuration

First, you'll want to make a minor config adjustment to your SSH server on the host machine (your Raspberry Pi). First, find your **sshd_config** file within the **etc** directory. You can run these commands by ssh-ing into the Raspberry Pi (with a sudo-capable account), or accessing the Pi directly and then opening a terminal.

Once you're in, run the command:

```
cd /etc/ssh
```

Make a backup of your sshd config file:

```
cp sshd_config sshd_config.ORIG
```

Now open the *original* file in a text editor with:

```
sudo nano sshd_config
```

You can choose any text editor you're comfortable with ([see here](https://gist.github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/43c045190356b0d5778c) for the nano text editor shortcuts). This is the main config file for the ssh server. Find and uncomment the following lines:

```
X11Forwarding yes
X11UseForwarding yes
```

Save and exit. Now you'll need to restart your Pi's SSH server with:

```
sudo systemctl restart sshd
```

### Windows (Client) Setup

You're done with your host. Now all you need to do is install an X server for Windows. There are a few options to choose from but I would go with Cygwin X which you can download [here](https://x.cygwin.com/). Install it and once you run it, it should spawn a little window on your client which will be used to display the X program. You can now test that X forwarding is happening by returning to your WSL shell and running the simple command:

```
xclock
```

A simple clock should appear in the window spawned by Cygwin. You can terminate the clock by returning to your WSL shell and hitting Ctrl+C.
If this command isn't recognized, you may first need to install x11-graphics applications on the host machine with:

```
sudo apt-get install x11-apps
```

X forwarding should now be enabled for you and you can now run most if not all of your Raspberry Pi's applications from Windows.

---

### Note on XDMCP, FreeNX

You may wish to take things a step further and set things up to run an entire desktop environment from your Pi rather than just app-by-app which is what X forwarding allows. Here are a couple common options available to you:

- XDMCP: This is the easiest to set up but is [notoriously insecure](https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/viewAlert.x?alertId=3473) and most authorities only recommend you ever run it on a trusted, wired LAN (like your home network). This may be more trouble than it's worth but if you're curious to look into it, see [this Rasp Pi thread for the initial setup](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=21246).
- FreeNX: More secure than XDMCP and probably worth the time to set up if you'll want to do this regularly and possibly from another network entirely. You'll need to install a FreeNX server on the host, then use another piece of software - **NoMachine** - on your Windows client. See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX) for a very detailed guide.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you please specify what shell you meant in "You can now test that X forwarding is happening by returning to your WSL shell"? Is this Bash inside Ubuntu inside Windows, for example?

Comment: If I add the line `X11UseForwarding yes`, the SSH server fails to restart. If I remove it, it restarts successfully.

Answer (score 20):

On the WSL shell, make sure you have exported the fully qualified DISPLAY

```bsh
export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0
```

The following **does not work**:

```bsh
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

:0.0 relies on a UNIX domain socket (instead of a TCP/IP socket) and somehow the X-forwarding doesn't get hooked up correctly.  I had the same problem.

update:  wsl2 is almost the same, but when using VcXsrv, you must check the `disable access control` box.

Comment: What is `VcXsrv` that you mentioned?

Comment: VcXsrv is a xwindows server application for windows.   Windows11 has a builtin server as part of WSL, so this may not be needed in the future.   Just google it.

Answer (score 4):

X11 considers the machine that DISPLAYS the graphical interface to be the X Windows SERVER, and the machine that provides the information to be displayed as the X Windows CLIENT. This is the reverse of the usual client/server relationship. Think of the local machine (the one with the physical display) as the *graphics server* and the remote machine as the *graphics client*.