# Why does XWin Server from Cygwin not open?

Tags: linux, windows-10, ssh, cygwin, x11-forwarding

I [installed](https://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/setup.html#setup-cygwin-x-installing) cygwins X Server to be able to X forward on Windows 10 as explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1332709/setting-up-x11-forwarding-over-ssh-on-windows-10-subsystem-for-linux). Now the installation completed and it finished without problems, but when I try to start the XWin Server as explained on the [offical site](https://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/using.html) a window opens shortly but immediately closes again. I tried to use the command `C:\cygwin64\bin\run.exe --quote /usr/bin/bash.exe -l -c "cd; exec /usr/bin/startxwin"` instead of using the shortcut but the same thing happens. A window opens briefly but no output in the console.
Starting a cygwin terminal and running `/usr/bin/startxwin` returns:

```
xinit: unable to run server "/usr/bin/XWin": No such file or directory
Use the -- option, or make sure that /usr/bin is in your path and
that "/usr/bin/XWin" is a program or a link to the right type of server
for your display.  Possible server names include:

XWin        X Server for the Cygwin environment on Microsoft Windows
Xvfb        Virtual frame buffer
Xfake       kdrive-based virtual frame buffer
Xnest       X server nested in a window on another X server
Xephyr      kdrive-based nested X server
Xvnc        X server accessed over VNC's RFB protocol
Xdmx        Distributed Multi-head X server

xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
```

I only found this issue https://github.com/babun/babun/issues/222, but it talks about some .babun folder which I don't even have so it looks like that doesn't apply to my problem. Shouldn't XWin be already installed when installing the different X packages? How can I get it?

Comment: No errors at all that's the thing, not even in the console.

Comment: what's happen if you run startxwin from bash session ? Logs are on `/var/log/xwin`

Comment: Did you install the `xorg-server` package?

Answer (score 0):

My antivirus moved the file to another place when I ran it the first time. I added an exception and disabled the antivirus temporarily but the file was already gonna when I ran it the second time. I restored it and now it works. That adding an exception does not automatically restore the file is beyond me...

Comment: can you open a `false positive` complaint with your antivirus provider ?