# Windows OpenSSH X11 client forwarding to a Linux server?

Tags: windows, ssh, powershell, openssh, x11-forwarding

I want to ssh to a Linux device in Windows with X11 forwarding using OpenSSH. I've installed the xming server running on `DISPLAY=:0` and set the environment variable using my powershell profile and system environment variables, all works fine with PuTTy.

But I want to ssh with X11 using the built-in OpenSSH, accessible via PowerShell and Command Prompt, not PuTTy. Any ideas on how to get this working?

So far I can ssh with the -X flag, but once authenticated - the error returned is...

```
ssh -X -Y root@jh-lenovo-lap1
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
```

Comment: As far as i know, windows builtin ssh does not support X forwarding. So its simply not possible

Comment: @Malik Well that sucks  But I won't give up hope just yet, surely considering how long xming has been around and that OpenSSH is open-source; someone has compiled some kind of OpenSSH client for windows that integrates with xming and powershell/cmd for x11 support? 

Comment: It seems possible with openssh in Windows Subsystem for Linux https://superuser.com/questions/1332709/setting-up-x11-forwarding-over-ssh-on-windows-10-subsystem-for-linux

Comment: To build on @Malik's comment, Microsoft has no intent to port X11 forwarding into Win32-OpenSSH, and there's ~20 or so option features that won't be ported listed on Microsoft Docs.

Comment: @JW0914 Do you have a link to that document? I'd like to read it.

Comment: @Malik I was thinking that was a possibility, but I'm looking for something a lot more native than virtualization just to get it, hence why I disregarded putty in this post.

Comment: @JamesHopwood [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_server_configuration#not-supported);  [GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1515) seems to imply I may have been wrong on it never going to be ported over, which was the last position I had [read](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1438#issuecomment-530513288) from one of the Microsoft devs a little over a year ago.